# 1 row if statement in PHP

Tags: php, html, dynamically-generated

sorry if this question is too simple but I can't figure it out on my own and I could use some help.

Basicly I've got this line of code:

```
$column_data_ar[] = (string)$employee_ar['functie'].$row = (!empty($row['functie_2']).'<br>'.$employee_ar['functie_2']);
```

And I want

```
'<br>'.$employee_ar['functie_2']
```

only to be posted when the column functie_2 is something else than NULL/Empty.

Thanks ahead for any replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's with

```
$row =(!empty($row['functie_2'])) ? '<br>'.$employee_ar['functie_2'] .'</br>' : '';
```

You could look at this page http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php to learn more about the Ternary Operator.

Comment: This solved it, thanks mirko911! And thanks for the link, that will surely help me learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try and let us know if this works for you or not. To test this you need `PHP7`.

```
<?php

$row = [];

$row['functie_2'] = 10;

$employee_ar['functie'] = 'some_value_';

$data = isset($row['functie_2']) ? $row['functie_2'] : null;

$column_data_ar[] = (string) $employee_ar['functie'] . $data ?: '';

var_dump($column_data_ar);
```

I am using the [Ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) of PHP and [Null coalescing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) opeator of `PHP7`.